# How to explore and select one file in Recycle Bin On Windows pragramming?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, recycle-bin

The env I'm using:

1. OS: Windows 10
2. IDE: Visual Studio 2015
3. Language: C++

I want to open recycle bin and select one file. It should be something like this:

```
cmdline = _T(" /select, \"");
cmdline += szPath;
cmdline += _T("\"");
::ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), _T("explorer.exe"), cmdline, NULL,  SW_SHOWNORMAL)
```

But recycle bin is different from file system. Any advice?

Comment: The recycle bin is indeed handled differently from the normal file system. There's further information on how to do this in C++ [located here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2783/How-to-programmatically-use-the-Recycle-Bin).

Comment: Most importantly, the files are in the Recycle Bin precisely because their old path on the file system is no longer valid.

Comment: @Octopoid Don't know if you'd be willing to extract an answer from that link, but that seems like what's desired here.

Comment: A full example is probably a bit long for an answer here, but all of the required functionality is available in this [github repo](https://gist.github.com/im-infamou5/03487b5b05336fcc69a1). Assuming you want to access the contents of the file as a one off thing you'd probably need to restore the file into a temp folder and then delete it again using the same approach, invoking shell commands. That link should cover how to restore directly to a different location to where it was originally deleted from too.

Comment: Raymond Chen also talked about the Recycle Bin on his blog: [How can I get information about the items in the Recycle Bin?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110830-00/?p=9773)

Comment: @Octopoid Get itmes in the Recycle Bin is solved, and open Recycle Bin is solved too. But how to select one specific item in the Opened Recycle Bin is the key point of question. Can you be more precisely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to open recycle bin by `ShellExecuteEx`, and the parameter of `plFile` should be `'explorer.exe'`. After opened recycle bin, using `FindWindow`, recyle bin could be found. Because I'm using `explorer`, which is developed and used by Microsoft itself, I didn't know the realization of explorer, so it stucked here.